# Telerik MVC DatePicker Control Globalization

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-mvc

Does anyone know what locales (languages) are actually supported "out of the box" by the Telerik DatePicker when setting ***Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().Globalization(true)***?  The DateTIme picker Globalization demo only gives a few examples, and I don't see any supporting .js files to support the locales anywhere in the code/demo.  Anyone know where to find this information documented?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the demo: [Telerik DatePicker Demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/datepicker/globalization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the English localization is supported out-of-the-box. Rest of the localization files/resources are provided by the community.

If you want to make your own localization just copy/paste the resource file for the widget you need, change the suffix to be to the culture you want and modify the values inside of it.

Just [like](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-localization.html) explained here for the Grid widget.